# Quicksort implementation in Python

Tags: python, beginner, sorting, quick-sort

I have written an implementation of Quicksort in Python. I am new to Python. Any suggestions for improvement or criticism on my use of Python?

```
def partition(a, lo, hi):
    i, j, v = lo+1, hi, a[lo]
    while(True):
        while(a[i] < v):
            i += 1
            if (i == hi): break    
        while(a[j] > v):
            j -= 1
            if (j == lo): break    
        if (i >= j): break            
        a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]    
    a[lo], a[j] = a[j], a[lo]
    return j

def sort(a, lo, hi):
    if (hi <= lo):
        return
    q = partition(a, lo, hi)
    sort(a, lo, q-1)
    sort(a, q+1, hi)
    assert isSorted(a, lo, hi)

def quick_sort(a):
    shuffle(a)
    sort(a, 0, len(a)-1)
    assert isSortedArray(a)

def isSorted(a, lo, hi):
    for i in range(lo, hi):
        if a[i+1] < a[i]:
            return False
    return True

def isSortedArray(a):
    for i in range(0, len(a)-1):
        if a[i+1] < a[i]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Where are `isSorted` and `isSortedArray`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't think that the implementation of those functions is essential to the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe They are just functions which check whether the array is sorted or not and returns a boolean. Just for assertion purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When describing quicksort partitioning, your `v` is typically called the "pivot".  The code would be clearer if you named the variable according to that convention.

You always choose `a[lo]` as the pivot.  However, that [produces pathological performance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot) when the input array is already sorted.

I would prefer to see

> ```
> while(a[i] < v):
>       i += 1
>       if (i == hi): break
> ```

… written as

```
while i < hi and a[i] < pivot:
    i += 1
```

---

Array index bounds usually work better when specified as inclusive-exclusive ranges, such that `sort(a, lo, hi)` means "sort `a` where `lo` ≤ index < `hi`".  This is a common convention — you can see it in Python's [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) and [slicings](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=slice#slicings).  Also, Java's [Arrays.sort(a, fromIndex, toIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int[],%20int,%20int%29) works with inclusive-exclusive ranges.

Some nice properties of inclusive-exclusive ranges are:

- `hi` - `lo` gives you the number of elements in the range.
- When creating a range for the entire array `a`, `hi` is just `len(a)`.  You save a "-1".
- When splitting [`lo`, `hi`) into two consecutive ranges, it becomes [`lo`, `mid`) and [`mid`, `hi`).  You save a "-1".
- In Python, you can conveniently write `for i in range(lo, hi)` for the most common type of iteration. (Admittedly, iterating backwards is uglier, but it's less common.)

Comment: @200_success Thanks for your suggestions. I had shuffled the array in the beginning using Knuth shuffle algorithm. I was wondering whether a better approach would be to shuffle first and then use the first element as the pivot or choosing a random element or median as the pivot.

Comment: Shuffling before sorting seems wasteful. You would be better off choosing a random element or the median of three elements as the pivot.

Comment: Should my partition function be also inclusive-exclusive range?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend consistently using inclusive-exclusive ranges everywhere.